Question about the Spectrum of a Matrix whose Entries contain Binomial Coefficients
For all $m,n \in \mathbb N,$ define
$$A_{m,n} = \left(\frac{1}{2} \right)^{m+n} \ \binom{m+n}{m} \ \frac{m-n}{m+n}.$$ Then, for each $N \in \mathbb N,$ define the skew-symmetric $N \times N$ matrix $\mathbf A_N,$ whose $(m,n)$-th entry is $A_{m,n}$ for all $1 \le m,n \le N.$ Finally, let $\lambda_{n,N}$ be the $n$-th largest eigenvalue of $\mathbf A_N$ (in modulus). More precisely, order the eigenvalues of $\mathbf A_N$ so that $$|\lambda_{1,N}|=|\lambda_{2,N}| \ge |\lambda_{3,N}| = |\lambda_{4,N}| \ge \dots.$$ Here, we assume if $\lambda_{2n-1,N}$ and $\lambda_{2n,N}$ are purely imaginary nonzero pairs, then $\lambda_{2n-1,N}$ has positive imaginary part.
Based on Mathematica, I have made the following conjecture
Conjecture 1: For small $n \in \mathbb N,$ we have $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \lambda_{2n-1,N} =\frac{i}{n \pi}.$$
However, I do not know how to prove Conjecture 1.
In my attempt to prove it, I have posed some intermediary conjectures that lead to Conjecture 1, stated below and based on Mathematica.
Conjecture 2: For each $q \in \mathbb N$ we have $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \text{tr} \left(\mathbf A_N^q \right) = - \frac{(-2)^q \  B_q}{q!},$$  where $B_1=0$ and $B_q$ is the $q$-th Bernoulli number for $q>1$.
Conjecture 3: If $p_N(z)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $\mathbf A_N$ divided by $(-1)^N,$ then $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \frac{p_N(z)}{z^{N+1}} = \sinh(1/z)$$ pointwise.
Questions
It appears that Conjecture 3 follows from Conjecture 2 via some use of Newton-Girard identities and properties of Bernoulli numbers.
However, is there a way to prove Conjecture 2 ? By the definition of the trace, this amounts to showing
$$\sum_{n_1 \ , \ \dots \ , \ n_{q} \in \mathbb N} A_{n_1,n_2} \ \dots \ A_{n_{q-1}, n_q} \ A_{n_q, n_1} = - \frac{(-2)^q \  B_q}{q!}$$ for each $q>1.$
Moreover, I have already proven a very similar looking identity: $$\sum_{n_1 \ , \ \dots \ , \ n_{q+1} \in \mathbb N} A_{n_1,n_2} \ \dots \ A_{n_{q}, n_{q+1}}  = - \frac{(-2)^q \  B_q}{q!}.$$ Observe the left hand side is not the limit of the trace of $\mathbf A_N^q$ as $N \rightarrow \infty,$ but rather the limit of the sum of all entries of $\mathbf A_N^q.$ Nevertheless, could this identity be used to prove Conjecture 2 ?
Secondly, is there a method to prove Conjecture 1 directly without using Conjecture 2 or Conjecture 3 ?

How does the eigenvector of $\lambda_{1,N}$ look like? Its coordinates may also have some asymptotics as $N\to\infty$

Let $\mathbf v_{1,N} \in \mathbb C^N$ be the associated eigenvector of $\lambda_{1,N}.$ For $N=2,3,$ I am seeing $\mathbf v_{1,2}=(i,1), \mathbf v_{1,3}= \left(-\frac{2+6i}{5}, \frac{4+3i}{5}, 1 \right)$ ...

... and $\mathbf v_{1,4}=\left{\frac{-4605-15
\sqrt{713001}+i \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}
\left(671660645+659079
\sqrt{713001}\right)}}{19336},\frac{5833+19 \sqrt{713001}+2 i
\sqrt{2 \left(178524509+63535
\sqrt{713001}\right)}}{38672},\frac{5219+17 \sqrt{713001}+9668 i
\sqrt{\frac{10548898}{5841889}-\frac{5350
\sqrt{713001}}{5841889}}}{19336},
1\right}$. But in general, I am seeing the coordinates of $\mathbf v_{1,N}$ spiral around the origin.
